# Change in the JavaScript code timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I have used the timer in the project. Do not have much familiarity with JavaScript.

I want to add one minute to timer when an event Happened. (without Refresh the page).

JavaScript code:

```
<div class="auto-due">
<div id="auction">
    <div style="float: left;width: auto;" class="soon" id="soon-glow"
        data-layout="group overlap"
        data-face="slot doctor glow"
        data-padding="false"
        data-scale-max="l"
        data-visual="ring color-light width-thin glow-progress length-70 gap-0 offset-65">
    </div>

    <div id="auction-info">
        <span>Time reminding to end</span>&nbsp;<div class="livicon" data-s="48" data-c="#fff" data-hc="0" data-n="clock"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    (function(){

        var i=0,soons = document.querySelectorAll('.auto-due .soon'),l=soons.length;
        for (;i<l;i++) {
            soons[i].setAttribute('data-due','<?= $endDateCountDown ?>');
            soons[i].setAttribute('data-now','<?= date("Y-m-d")."T".date("H:i:s") ?>');
        }

    }());

</script>

<script src="<?= $this->theme->getUrl('js/soon.min.js'); ?>" data-auto="false"></script>
<script>
  if ('addEventListener' in document) {
    var showDemo = function(e){
        var btn = e.target;
        btn.style.display = 'none';
        var wrapper = e.target.parentNode;
        var panel = wrapper.querySelector('.el-sample');
        panel.style.display = 'block';
        var nodes = e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.soon');
        for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
            Soon.create(nodes[i]);
        }
    };
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.demo-button');
    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click',showDemo);
    }
  }
  var soons = document.querySelectorAll('.auto-due .soon');
  for(var i=0;i<soons.length;i++) {
      Soon.create(soons[i]);
  }
</script>
</div>
```

$endDateCountDown variable show the end time and date of timer.

date & time for this timer must have this format:

2015-11-09T23:10:09

How do I add one minute to the timer without Refresh the page?

Comment: Question seems unclear...Can you share what is your expected output and what is not working ?

Comment: create a fiddle for better understanding.

Comment: The code uses a propritary js component called Soons. You should refer to their documentation then update your question. http://codecanyon.net/item/soon-countdown-pack-responsive-jquery-plugin/9485513

Comment: If your question is not related to the server side code (which it doesnt seem to be) you should post the generated HTML and Javascript, code with other code mixed in is needlessly difficult for an outsider to understand and it leaves us with questions like "ok ...what does such and such  other code variable evaluate to?" With generated code, we can see exactly what everything is